# Two OkHttpClients with Two Caches - Odd Behavior

Tags: android, caching, okhttp

My app currently has one `OkHttpClient` (v3.2.0) that is used for:

1. Retrofit
2. Picasso
3. Uploading images/videos to a cloud media service
4. An [`HttpDataSource`](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer/upstream/HttpDataSource.html) for videos using [`ExoPlayer`](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/) ([here's the implementation)](https://gist.github.com/eygraber/8e935e19eedc70d2d8e3)

I want to use separate `OkHttpClients` for Retrofit and the media use cases because:

1. I want to keep their caches separate
2. The media `OkHttpClient` will have some specific `Interceptors` that the Retrofit one should not have

After making the changes, I provide each instance of `OkHttpClient` with its own `Cache`; both are in the app's cache directory, one using the directory `http`, and one using `media`. Both instances are set up the same way (uses the same `CookieJar`, and `Interceptors` in their `Builders`; the only difference is that there are different `Cache` instances passed to them). The cache works perfectly with Picasso, but exhibits weird behavior when used with the `OkHttpDataSource`.

The URL that is passed to `OkHttpDataSource` is an endpoint on my application server that redirects (302) to the cloud media service. This is the same process that we use for images/Picasso and that works fine.

My basic testing steps for caching are:

1. Use the `OkHttpDataSource` to play a video (with my application server sending back correct cache headers)
2. FC the app and reopen it
3. Put the device in airplane mode
4. Use the `OkHttpDataSource` to play a video (should play even though there's no internet connection)

When I use one `OkHttpClient` everything works fine. When I use two instances as described above, the response from my application server is cached (the 302), but when it tries to resolve the `Location` header, an `IOException` is thrown saying that it can't resolve the address. Again, this doesn't happen when I only use one instance of `OkHttpClient`. Furthermore, when I have 2 instances, if I use the Retrofit instance for the `OkHttpDataSource`, the caching works fine.

I was trying to figure out what was going on by debugging `DiskLruCache`, but was having difficulties because having the debugger attached seemed to be having side effects. What I was able to observe was that in some situations the cache entry for the redirected URL was getting removed because its `DiskLruCache.Entry.readable` was always set to `false`. As far as I can tell, this was because `DiskLruCache.completeEdit` was getting called with `success = false`, but I'm not sure why that happened. Again, it was not an issue when only using one instance of `OkHttpClient`, or using the REST instance instead of the media one for `OkHttpDataSource`.

Answer (score 0):

OkHttp’s cache will only store complete responses. The first time you download the file, are you reading the entire response body and then calling close() on that stream?

Comment: I haven't explicitly verified that the whole file was downloaded, but throughout my extensive testing I played the entire video file, which would lead me to believe that it downloaded the whole thing. Another point is that if I revert my 2 client code, or even use the other client instance it works. Since the other client is used with Retrofit, is it possible that Retrofit tweaks some parameter on it that would mask/fix the issue? Also, is there any more information I can provide to help in solving this issue?

Comment: Just re-read your question, and while I don't explicitly call `ResponseBody.close()`, `OkHttpDataSource.close()` does get called from `ExoPlayer` and that calls `ResponseBody.close()`. I've verified that `ResponseBody.close()` does get called when using one `OkHttpClient` instance (and the cache works), and when using two (and the cache doesn't work). In both cases I play the entire video, so I would assume the whole body was read.